# Woocommerce Export Parent Products

Tags: woocommerce, export, wpallimport

for my woocommerce e-shop i use WpAllImport plugin for importing my products with their variations. Typically one product with the variations is shown below
[image]
The parent product has no price/sale price values and the price/sale price values are all the same for all variations.
Now i want to export an xml file with only my parents products with WpAllExport plugin. As there is no price/sale price values the tag `<price> </price>` and `<sale price> </sale price>`is return empty with no values.
I realise that i need php function for the export to pass any variation price/sale price to parent product price fields.
Does someone help me with the php function i have to write?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally I add the following code and it works fine.

```
<?php
function get_regular_price_for_xml($parent, $price)
{
    if ($parent == "0") {
        global $product;
        $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        if (!empty($product_variations) && is_array($product_variations)) {
            $variation_product_id = $product_variations[0]['variation_id'];
            $variation_product = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_product_id);
            return $variation_product->regular_price;
        } else {
            return $price;
        }
    } else {
        return $price;
    }
}
```